# Can Ember-hash-helper-polyfill be used for app in ember version < 1.13?

Tags: ember.js, ember-addon

The Readme for Ember-hash-helper-polyfill says that it can be used in ember versions 1.13 -> 2.2. Does this mean it can not be used in older versions(such as 1.11)?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this out. Looks like it works for version 1.11 as well.

Initially, I was getting an error because the consuming addon was yielding a closure action in the hash.